# iOS/Apple App Store Release Process

Tags: ios, app-store

I've been trying to find some guidelines on the overall process for releasing an iOS app.  The documentation on Apple's iOS Dev Center doesn't seem clear.  I've found some sites that try to explain aspects of the process, but I haven't been able to find a clear, conscise guide that explains some of my questions, such as:

1. What do I have to do within my project (ie info.plist file changes, target/build settings, etc.)
2. I am using In-App Purchases.  It is working in my sandbox, but what do I need to do (if anything else) to make sure this works when my app is released?  As far as I can tell from what I've read, there is no way to test this in live environment until after the app appears on the app store.
3. Is there any other provisioning/certificates needed beyond what I have used when developing my app?
4. Anything else that I am overlooking?

If you know of a site (or sites) that explains this in more detail, it would be much appreciated.  After searching for hours I can't seem to find answers to these questions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/ApplicationDevelopment/RM_DevelopingForAppStore/DevelopingForAppStore/DevelopingForAppStore.html) from Apple on "preparing for app store submission"? It's pretty clear on the steps you have to take to get onto the app store.

In short:

1. No specific changes, but you have to archive for a device rather than building for testing.
2. In App Purchasing will work on the app store without any more configuration
3. You need a distribution certificate for when you build an archive for the app store, make it in your iOS Provisioning Portal, under Provisioning page and Distribution tab.

Comment: Page is not available. Refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html